# Using WhatsApp on Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: 8.0, whatsapp

Recently, when trying to use WhatsApp on my Samsung Ativ S, I get a message saying that as of Jan 18, 2018 WhatsApp will no longer be working on Windows Phone 8.0. When exiting the message, I can use the application without any problem (valid today, 11 days before Jan 18, 2018). If the above is true, what can I do? Will it work on Windows Phone 8.1 (which I currently don't have)?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this WhatsApp FAQ article](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000006), they will no longer support the app on Windows Phone 8.0. WP 8.1, however, appears to still be supported, per this quote from the same article (emphasis mine):

> ... we recommend upgrading to a newer OS version, or to a newer Android running OS 4.0+, iPhone running iOS 7+, or **Windows Phone 8.1+** so that you can continue using WhatsApp.

Even disregarding WhatsApp support, you should update your phone to 8.1 because it is a significant improvement over 8.0. [This article on GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_ativ_s_finally_gets_updated_to_windows_phone_81-news-10103.php) says that the Samsung Ativ S started receiving the 8.1 update back in 2014.