# WhatsApp is unsupported on Nokia Lumia 520

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-520

I'm using Nokia Lumia 520 version 8227. When I log into WhatsApp, there's a caution about my phone being unsupported with a message that WhatsApp for Windows Phone expired on 31/12/2017.

Can I still use WhatsApp on Lumia 520?

Comment: Is your phone running Windows Phone 8.0 or 8.1? If 8.0, then see [this question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/16546/1401).

Answer (score 1):

According to [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/wp/21478428), support for Windows Phone 8 has been discontinued on December 31, 2017.

> WhatsApp will no longer be supported on Windows Phone 8.0 after
>   December 31, 2017. This means that if you are currently using WhatsApp
>   on a Windows Phone 8.0, you will be able to continue to use WhatsApp
>   on that phone before this date.

**Solution:** Update your phone to Windows Phone 8.1. According to this softpedia [article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Nokia-Lumia-520-and-Lumia-925-Now-Receiving-Windows-Phone-8-1-Update-at-AT-T-453062.shtml) Lumia 520 did recieve an update to Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: As a side note, upgrading your phone to WP8.1 (in addition to bringing security fixes and other improvements) will also let you make voice calls via WhatsApp.